# Inflate a view to a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

How can i inflate my other view to my linearlayout? 
It would be better to show my layout first.

list.xml

```
        <FrameLayout >

            <ImageView/>

            <ProgressBar />

    </FrameLayout>      

    <TextView/>

    <TextView />
```

then , main.xml

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

So, i want my `list.xml` to populate `linearlayout`. 
The data of my `list.xml` is from my json.
I have spent a lot of time changing my implementation to this one.

I've tried doing this:
(i first disregard the image)

```
//after parsing json and 
//and doing this..

        product = new ProductRowItem(imageUrl, sName, productId, desc, Integer.parseInt(imgHeight), Integer.parseInt(imgWidth), productOwnerId);
                                productItems.add(product);
//...
//by the way, product item is a pojo..


        for(ProductRowItem product : productItems){
            View productView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtProductName = (TextView) productView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            holder.txtProductDesc = (TextView) productView.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);

            productView.setTag(holder);

            holder.txtProductName.setText(product.getProductName());
            holder.txtProductDesc.setText(product.getProductDesc());
        }
```

Nothing was displayed...
Any ideas regarding inflating to linearlayout is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance..
Also, I've already used [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). And i have a reason why I won't be using this. Not that it's bad, but I can't override and there's no `overscrollBy` method

Answer (score 0):

You inflate the view but you don't add "productView" created to your main view or in a groupview displayed into your main view !

Your inflate is correct (if the holder is correct)

The holder is useless in this case because normally is created for no inflate a layout again, and just fill the view allocated.

In your code :
You initialize always the holder inflated by your view !

Comment: "You inflate the view but you don't add "productView" created to your main view or in a groupview displayed into your main view !" sorry, i didn't get it..

Comment: What you do with "productview" after the "for" statement ?